# If anyone can do it, then Jones can do it, too

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

1. If anyone can do it, then Jones can
2. If Jones can do it, then anyone can

I am confused whether to use forall or there exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If anyone can do it, then Jones can (do it)," says, "For anyone: if they can do it, then Jones can do it."

$$\forall x~\big(D(x)\to D(j)\big)$$

- $\small\text{ Which is equivalent to }(\exists x~D(x))\to D(j)~$

"If Jones can do it, then anyone can (do it)," reads: $D(j)\to\forall x~D(x)$ or $$\forall x~\big(D(j)\to D(x)\big)$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

If $ X$ can do it, we will write : $P(X)$.

The conditionnal : if p then q is represented by $ p \implies q$.

So, the proposition : if any can do it then Jones can do it becomes

$$\forall X \;P(X) \implies \; P(Jones)$$

The second one is
$$P(Jones)\implies \forall X P(X)$$
Here, it clearly means that if Jones can, everyone $\forall$ can.

Comment: It looks like statement is if there is someone who can do it implies jones can do it. Shouldnot we use there exists then ?

Comment: Anyone can be "everyone" or "someone", Here it should be "someone". I think that the first question should be $\exists x (C(x)\rightarrow C(Jone))$. In the second question, "anyone" should be "everyone".

Comment: @JessicaGriffin $(\forall x P(x)) \implies Q$ is tautologically equivalent to $\exists x (P(x) \implies Q)$.  So you are both saying the same thing, but you are intuitively logically transmuting the statement into it's existential form before translating to symbols.

Comment: @DanielV intuitively doesnot appear so

Comment: @JessicaGriffin Read Question 4 of Example 2.1.3 In Velleman should make you feel confident on these two questions,

Comment: @torontohrb thanks

Comment: @JessicaGriffin Oh my fault, I thought you wrote that message.  It was toronto.  Oops.